# Postgres stops listening on IP (Azure) / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, azure, networking

I have a Postgres 9.3.9 running on Azure. I have a rails webserver connecting to it.

I can connect to it fine from the rails server for a while. I connect like this:

```
me@server:~$ psql -h db.mydomain.com -U myuser mydb
```

Then a while later (30 mins, or hours - it's random) I can't connect anymore and I need to restart the server (/etc/init.d/postgresql restart) to be able to connect again.

When it stops responding, I can't telnet to port 5432 - it does not respond.

**This is what I get with psql:**

```
me@server:~$ psql -h db.mydomain.com -U myuser mydb
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "db.mydomain.com" (x.x.x.x) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**This is what I get with a Capistrano deploy:**

```
initialize': could not connect to server: Connection timed out (PG::ConnectionBad)
 ** [out :: x.x.x.x] Is the server running on host "db.mydomain.com" (x.x.x.x) and accepting
 ** [out :: x.x.xx] TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

**Other points:**

- When it stops responding, my rails web app still works OK from a browser
- As soon as I restart the postgresql server it accepts the connection
- It is intermittent, if it isn't responding and I leave it for a while (10 minutes? hours?) it might work the next time

Comment: paste your postgresql.conf file OR write down the max_connections value, if the browser still works it have to be this.

Comment: I just checked max_connections and it is set to 100.   

I changed it to 200 and then restarted the server.

I'll see if that helps. 

But I don't think this server would ever hit 100 connections.. is `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` the best way to check connections?

Comment: ok check it out now if still stop responding.

Comment: ended up giving up and using an ssh tunnel instead